# How can i disable default hover titles globally on a vuetify project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

When i come over to anywhere in vuetify project for instance; data-table, alerts or buttons..
I see the default hover titles.

[image: first example]

On the first example i see it when i hover on the rows.

[image: second example]

On the second example i see it when i hover on the alert divs.

[image: third example]

On the third example i see it when i hover on the buttons.
My question is how can i disable it globally ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `title` attribute set on the container? Where do you think the datatable, the alert and the button all get the same value "employeelists" from?